# No cierra la sesion PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una duda con Sesiones en PHP.
Tengo una pagina llamada `principal.php` la cual es un `login` y si haces el `login` correcto te lleva a una pagina llamada `messenger.php`,y en la pagina `messenger` al cerrar sesión no la cierra,se puede volver a entrar directamente con el link de `messenger.php`

Comprobación para ver si la sesión se inicio:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
{
echo "Bienvenido: " . $_SESSION['login'];
}
else
{
 header("Location: principal.php");
}
```

---

```
<?php
session_start();

// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 

header("Location: principal.php")
?>
```

Cierro sesión pero igual se puede acceder a `messenger.php`  directo con el link sin necesidad de `logearse`. ¿Alguien me ayuda por favor?

Comment: En messenger.php estas validando si hay sesion activa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que colocas el session_start() en el archivo de logout, se supone que ya la sesión esta iniciada.

Esto te puede ayudar:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
  $_SESSION[$key] = NULL; 
}

session_unset();

session_destroy();

header('Location:'principal.php');
```